# insert with map library is not working

Tags: c++, dictionary, insert

I have the following program and giving problem when doing inserting into the map:

```
      static std::map<std::string,void *> name_data_map;
      std::map<std::string,void *>::iterator iter=name_data_map.find(name) ;


    if(  iter == name_data_map.end() )
    {
            tmp_data = (void *) malloc ( mt_get_dkstat_size() );
            errorCode = getsproxy(tmp_data , name );
            name_data_map.insert(pair<std::string,void *>(name,tmp_data) );

    }


   memcpy(*data, iter->second,  mt_get_dkstat_size() ) ;
```

after the insertion, `tmp_data` is getting corrupted. and also i want to understand what is the difference between the two types of insert:

```
name_data_map.insert(pair<std::string,void *>(name,tmp_data) );
name_data_map.insert(make_pair(name,tmp_data) );
```

Thanks for the advanced reply

Comment: What is `*data` in `memcpy(*data, ...);` ?

Comment: The map's value type is `std::pair<const std::string, void*>`.

Comment: *data type is : void **data. call by reference.

Comment: Is memory allocated for `data` somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

`iter` would still point to the `end()` of your `map` if it doesn't already exist.

Try this:

```
static std::map<std::string,void *> name_data_map;
std::map<std::string,void *>::iterator iter=name_data_map.find(name) ;


if (iter == name_data_map.end())
{
        tmp_data = (void *)malloc(mt_get_dkstat_size());
        errorCode = getsproxy(tmp_data, name);
        // Fix:
        std::pair<std::map<std::string,void>::iterator,bool> ret;
        ret = name_data_map.insert(pair<std::string,void *>(name,tmp_data));
        iter = ret.first;
}

memcpy(*data, iter->second, mt_get_dkstat_size());
```

EDIT: To answer your question about the differences between the two methods, they are basically the same as `make_pair` is implemented as:

```
template <class T1,class T2>
  pair<T1,T2> make_pair (T1 x, T2 y)
  {
    return ( pair<T1,T2>(x,y) );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply errors are ::The call does not match any parameter list for "operator=".        "implicit std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,void *,std::less<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > >,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,void *> >,0> >::iterator::operator=(const std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,void *,std::less<std::basic_s..." is not a viable candidate.

Comment: Apologies; that `insert` method returns a pair with the iterator as the first element - I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
void *tmp_data;
if(  iter == name_data_map.end() ) {
        tmp_data = (void *) malloc ( mt_get_dkstat_size() );
        errorCode = getsproxy(tmp_data , name );
        name_data_map[name] = tmp_data;
} else {
    tmp_data = iter->second;
}

memcpy(*data, tmp_data,  mt_get_dkstat_size() ) ;
```

The problem with your original code is that you dereference `iter`, even when it is equal to `.end()`.

---

Or, if you prefer to use `insert` instead of `operator[]`, try this:

```
auto pair = name_data_map.insert(std::make_pair(name, (void*)0));
if(pair.second) {
    pair.first->second = (void*)malloc( mt_get_dkstat_size() );
    errorCode = getxproxy(tmp_data, name);
}

memcpy(*data, pair.first->second,  mt_get_dkstat_size() ) ;
```

This will combine the `.find()` and `.insert()` into one operation, saving you one log(N) search per insertion.